# Downloading sites from a list

Tags: python, wget

So, I am a bit new to python, and I can't get my head to wrap around why this code snippet is not working.

In short, I have a list of 500 sites, all in the following format: `https://www.domain . com/subfolder/subfolder` separated by a new line, and I am trying to download them. This is the code:

```
    import wget

    f = open("500_sites.txt", "r") 
    content = f.readlines()
    url = ""
    for x in range(1, len(content)):
        print(content[x])
        wget.download(content[x], 'index.html')
        input("wait a bit")
```

I am expecting the code to read the text file line by line in the `content` list. Then, I would like the `wget.download()` function to download the whole source code of the `content[x]` webpage.

Using the `wget.download()` with a given variable it works perfectly:

```
    ...
    url = "https://domain . com/subfolder/subfolder"
    wget.download(url, 'index.html')
    ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: _this code snippet is not working_ Saying "it is not working" doesn't help.  Tell us what the code _actually does_, and explain how that isn't what you _expected_.

Comment: the error I get is:

urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: I will edit the post, adding more information

Comment: That is because one of the links you are trying to wget returns a 403. You should handle that exception if it occurs using a try except. Read into the 403 exception. You may want to also consider that in a list of 500 domains, you may get other error codes. If not handled, the program will crash. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: 403 Forbidden means the web server decided you aren't allowed to access that document.

Comment: Also, every request is being saved to `index.html`, which means that file is being destroyed and overwritten each time through the loop.

Comment: I know about the overwriting, I just want to make this part to work

Comment: the `input()` function stops the program until you type something and press enter - is this the problem?

Comment: Weird thing is, that if I don't read the sites from a file, it works just fine

Comment: As mentioned above, you have two issues. You are receiving error codes from wget that are unhandled. And as Azamat mentioned, you have an input command that is waiting for your input before proceeding to the next website in your list. Perhaps you want to use Time.sleep(n)?

Comment: I want to stop the program, I want to see which site is the program working on

Comment: What is the last website printed before you receive your error?

Comment: When you use `readlines()`, each line has a trailing newline `\n` character.  You can use `.strip()` to remove the newline.  Try this: `wget(content[x].strip())`

Comment: Absolutely no website is downloaded, the program gives the error before even downloading the first website

Comment: What is the value that is printed for the first website?

Comment: Thank you John, that was the problem. Thought that it was stripping the contents automatically

Comment: The printed values look fine, did not notice that at the end of every string there is a new line, I don't want to use this as an excuse, but as I said, I am new to this language.